# Why the Mangalsutra thread should not be changed during the period of pregnancy?

Tags: rituals, marriage, mangalasutra

In Hindu religion after marriage Mangalsutra thread is worn by the ladies. They will change the threads after some days/months.

However, during the period when the woman is pregnant, she is not allowed to change the thread, what is reason behind this?